# AppCache all images in a folder

Tags: html, caching, browser-cache, application-cache, html5-appcache

I have a web client that gets its data (including images) from a web service.

I'm already able to cache the web client so the user can use it even if he/she is offline.  However I'm not able to cache the images.

Here's what is in my manifest:

```
CACHE: .... http://192.168.20.50:8080/ws/images/products/*
```

Any ideas how can I cache all the images in that folder? I'm using the full URL because my client has different URL.  (http://192.168.20.50:8080/client)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CACHE section does not support wildcards. Here you have to explicitly insert every image. But On server side you could do that dynamically while list all files and append their names to the manifest.